# Python scrapy, how to do a random delay between each request in a single spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider where i want to have a delay between each request, but i don't want it to be a fixed number rather a random amount of time between two bounds, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, avoid to use `time.sleep` because it blocks Twisted reactor and thus eliminates all the advantages of Scrapy concurrency.

By default, Scrapy's `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting adds random delay in range between `0.5 * DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and `1.5 * DOWNLOAD_DELAY` seconds. This behaviour manages by `RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting which is true by default.

Docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY

Comment: Ah i wasn't aware of RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY